# How elixir keep the accumulator

Tags: elixir

I am trying to understand elixir stream.
First I have a list that iterate through a range and multiple with 2.

```
iex(5)>   stream = 1..3 |>
...(5)>   Enum.map(&IO.inspect(&1)) |>
...(5)>   Enum.map(&(&1 * 2)) |>
...(5)>   Enum.map(&IO.inspect(&1)) |>
...(5)>   Enum.reduce(4, &+/2)
1
2
3
2
4
6
16
```

Here everything is clear, every enum return a list for further processing the list. It iterates four times for each element in the list.
Lets build it with stream:

```
iex(4)>   stream = 1..3 |>
...(4)>   Stream.map(&IO.inspect(&1)) |>
...(4)>   Stream.map(&(&1 * 2)) |>
...(4)>   Stream.map(&IO.inspect(&1)) |>
...(4)>   Enum.reduce(4, &+/2)
1
2
2
4
3
6
16
```

Here it iterates only at once for each number in the range not like the example above with **enum**. What I do not understand is, how the accumulator of Enum.reduce keep the value and make a recursive call by them self, when it iterates only once?
When I iterate an enum as follow:

```
iex(25)> f = fn(x, y) ->
...(25)> IO.puts(y)
...(25)> x + y
...(25)> end
#Function<12.54118792/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(26)> iter = 1..5 |> Enum.reduce(4, f)
4
5
7
10
14
19
```

then I can imaging, how **enum.reduce** pass the accumulator to the next recursive call.

But how the stream pass the accumulator for the next recursion call, if the iteration by stream execute only once?

Comment: Your question is very confused - it's not that complicated take a look at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html

Comment: You can go to Elixir language in GitHub and take a look at the source code although it may be a mapping from Erlang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what it is that you're missing/asking, but let me give explaining this a try. First, you have to know how streams work and are represented in Elixir: streams are just a set of functions to operate on an enumerable. When you compose streams (e.g., `1..3 |> Stream.map(...) |> Stream.map(...)`), you're not doing anything "concrete" with the stream, you're just adding functions to the list of functions that will be used to process the initial enumerable. When call `Enum.reduce/3` with a stream, that's when you start to iterate over the enumerable (one element at a time).

Your example could maybe be understood better by inspecting the progress of `Enum.reduce/3` too:

```
iex> printer1 = fn el -> IO.puts "1st iteration, el: #{inspect el}"; el end
iex> printer2 = fn el -> IO.puts "2nd iteration, el: #{inspect el}"; el end
iex> reducer = fn el, acc ->
...>   IO.puts "reducing, el: #{inspect el}, acc: #{inspect acc}\n"
...>   el + acc
...> end
iex> 1..3 |> Stream.map(printer1) |> Stream.map(&(&1 + 10)) |> Stream.map(printer2) |> Enum.reduce(0, reducer)
1st iteration, el: 1
2nd iteration, el: 11
reducing, el: 11, acc: 0

1st iteration, el: 2
2nd iteration, el: 12
reducing, el: 12, acc: 11

1st iteration, el: 3
2nd iteration, el: 13
reducing, el: 13, acc: 23

36
```

As you can see, there's little magic happening: when we call `Enum.reduce/3`, the stream starts to get unfolded and we go through each element mapping the three functions and calling `reducer` on it and the accumulator.

It may help you to study the docs for the [`Enumerable`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enumerable.html) protocol as that protocol is used to get elements out of streams (usually one at a time). When you chain `Enum.map/2` operations (as you do in your first example), `Enum.reduce/3` will receive a list as its first argument, so the `Enumerable` protocol for lists will be used: its implementation just iterates over the list and "yields" elements of the list to `Enumerable.reduce`, one at a time. When you chain `Stream.map/2` operations instead, `Enum.reduce/3` will receive a stream and thus the `Enumerable` protocol for streams will be used: its implementation takes each element out of the original enumerable (`1..3`), applies the stream operations (the chain of `Stream.map/2` in this case), and yields their results one at a time.

Hope I've made things clearer for you, please ask anything if you still have doubts :).

Comment: When the stream pass the value one by one, there is no pointer to the next value. When I use only `Enum.map` it will intermediate a list and the list is going to past to next `Enum.map`, the list has always a pointer to the next value. When I am using the stream, only one value is going to pass, how `Enum.map` knows the pointer for the next value? You know what I mean?

Comment: @zero_coding nope, I'm not sure what you mean :| If I understand your doubts correctly, you're not sure how the stream keeps track of where it is in the enumerable. My advice (as said in the answer) is to study the `Enumerable` protocol: the way we implement over an enum "lazily" (one elem at a time) is to "yield" an element of the enum and a continuation function that will recursively yield and return a continuation, and so on. Look for `:suspend`-related things in the docs for `Enumerable`.